# ServerSocket.accept() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, serversocket

I was reading about AsyncTask and I tried the simple program below with Socket. But if you use the accept method, the SendTask().execute() will not work. How can I make it work?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ServerTask().execute();
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SendTask().execute();
            System.out.println("1234");
        }
    });
}

class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7000);
            serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("data accpet");
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

class SendTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("Send!!!!!!!!!");
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you use the accept method, the output:

```
07-10 09:29:33.940: I/System.out(19660): 1234
```

If you not use the accept method, the output:

```
07-10 09:31:00.070: I/System.out(20174): 1234

07-10 09:31:00.070: I/System.out(20174): Send!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: `the B will not work` ????

Comment: Wut? You are immediately closing your ServerSocket. SendTask does not do anything at all. What are you trying to achieve? What is B?  What does "use the accept method" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system async tasks will not run in parallel but sequentially. Thats why you dont see the log of the second asynctask as the first with the accept never finishes when no client connects. Nice try though. Use threads instead.

Comment: Nice to know.  But what does thar mean? DEPENDING on your system? AsyncTask and do in background are both quite selfexplaining phrases. Why do they not do what they tell us to do?

Comment: Depending on the used Android version. Sorry i do not know which ones from memory. Have nothing at hand now. Just search/google this problem and you find.

Comment: I soon will encounter simillar sitiation. Though I already inherited from Thread, i still was playing with some thoughts to change this approach. By the way, are You familiar with the more or less "common approach" of a "socket StateObject" ?

Comment: With threads you will not have this problem. No sorry. Don't know about that object.

Comment: Some technique, were You have one Socket sending and reading sequentially , and another socket is prepared in order to only receive  asynchroneously. Means, an applicarion can also receive "advices" in order to react, so a send/read need not always to be done. Does that sound more common  to You ?

Comment: Hmm.. Please rephrase the tasks using clientsocket and serversocket. Who does what.

Comment: There is an application, which communicates with a Server which is responsible to control hardware devices. The application sends commands to the server and recieves reaponses by a simple Socket. The server also can explicitely send information to this application, which in this case would act as a Server.  So the second socket ONLY listens.

Comment: Ok. Nothing wrong with that. That's implementable with sockets. I do not see a need to intoduce something extra like state object. But then I don't know what that is. But .. the app could also just use one (client)socket. As the client also has to be prepared for unsolicited messages the client should always try to read in a loop in a thread.

Comment: Thats right. The second socket( by the way it is c#, and i must port that stuff to java for android)  has an asynchroneous delegate assigned which listens on another thread. So i would go good with inheriting from thread an creating a server socket in that derived class?

Comment: Well that will be the way to go I think. Succes!

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to see `"data accpet"` in your output, you have to get an incoming connection from another device on port 7000. `System.out.println("data accpet");` won't run until `serverSocket.accept();` returns, and `serverSocket.accept();` won't return until a connection is made.


The [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) for this behavior states:

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.